# bash command substitution's result not consistent

Tags: bash

I have a script.

cat /root/test/ddd.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
s=/root/test/ddd.sh
ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep
result=$(ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep | wc -l)
echo $result
```

when i execute it, the result is weird, it shows that there is two line matched.

```
[root@l2 test]# /root/test/ddd.sh
root     15361 15032  0 09:52 pts/18   00:00:00 /bin/bash         /root/test/ddd.sh
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're running a subshell. That is, the `$(...)` piece causes bash to `fork`, thereby creating two (nearly) *identical* processes. By identical, I mean basically everything except for process ID, parent process ID, return code from the `fork`, and I can't think of anything else. But one thing that *does* remain the same for sure is the command line.  Both of them will be "`/bin/bash /root/test/ddd.sh`". So, inside the `result=$(...)`, there will be exactly one extra process that matches.

You can see this, for example, by removing the `| wc -l` piece at the end of your `$(...)`, and, to make it more readable, enclose the echo's argument in quotes:

```
result="$(ps -ef | grep $s | grep -v grep)"
echo "$result"
```

Here you will see that there are two bashes, and the PPID of one is the PID of the other, showing the parent-child relationship.